# How to find a set of vectors given its span?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We're learning about what vector spaces and subspaces are in linear algebra, and this question is really confusing me:

> Let *W* be the set of all vectors of the form shown, where *a*, *b*, and *c* represent arbitrary real numbers. In each case, either find a set *S* of vectors that spans *W* or give an example to show that *W* is *not* a vector space.

> $\begin{bmatrix}a - b\\b - c\\c-a\\b\end{bmatrix}$

I know that this *can* be written as the span of a set of vectors. I also know that this span would be a 1D subspace (line) in R4, since it has 1 pivot and 4 rows. I just don't know how I would go about finding the set of vectors that this is the span for. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: write the given general vector in the form
$$\begin{bmatrix}a-b\\b-c\\c-a\\b\end{bmatrix} = a \begin{bmatrix}?\\?\\?\\?\end{bmatrix} + b \begin{bmatrix}?\\?\\?\\?\end{bmatrix} + c \begin{bmatrix}?\\?\\?\\?\end{bmatrix}$$